# Changing the title of a research paper before the submission of the camera-ready version

Tags: publications, conference

My research paper has been accepted for the IEEE ICCSE conference. I am planning to change the title of the research paper before the submission of the camera-ready version. This would be a slight modification which will not affect the context of my research. Would it be possible to do so? Is it okay if I request to change the title of my paper?

Comment: You need to inform the chairs, beyond changing the paper title in the PDF. Otherwise, the conference program, bibliographic record, and so on might keep the old title. It happened to me for a workshop. Here's an example which somehow ended up the same way (maybe for the same reasons) from a top-tier CS conference, 23 years ago: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=99583.99587.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, you can do this, but you need to get an explicit permission from the programme chair(s). I would also suggest thoroughly explaining the change, as such a change request might indicate that you did a lousy job preparing the paper before the submission itself.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if they denied permission for any reasonable title change, but it's definitely crucial to let them know.  (If you just change the title on the camera-ready version without any other notice, it will cause confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with conferences in this regard, but, I have done once with one of my journal paper.

After second revision (minor), I felt that the title was too long. So, I shortened the title that does not change the intention of the paper. For this, while submitting the cover letter (to the Editor/Editor in Chief), I declared that I have intentionally changed the title that does not necessarily change the goal of the manuscript. The paper was accepted and was subsequently published.

As others point out, even though it is a conference paper, you should explicitly state or inform the program chair about this.